# JQuery fullcalendar row-height increment for weekly(Agenda) view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

Can anyone please tell me how to increase the row height for an Agenda view in jquery-fullcalendar plugin? (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)

**Additional info** : 
I am able to able to bind the custom data to calendar but row-height is
very limited and not showing entire text which I want to display for an event.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks

Comment: I am sure that you could find it in the  full calendar css - but the workaround that I used was to set slotDuration to 15 mins rather than the default 30 - so therefore the same event duration covered more rows in the calendar. not pretty but it works

Comment: as a workaround, you could add `overflow: auto` to the closest parent `a` tag which should have at least one of these classes `fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable`.

This will not increase the height, but whole content would be viewable through a scroll in case it's more than available height.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the row height you can just put this in your styles:

```
.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
    height: 3.5em;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8rcnqmb/122/)